# How to use switch-case with strings in c#?

Tags: c#, string, switch-statement

I'm trying to make a really basic calculator program.  I am getting the following error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'string'

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _2019_03_21
{
    class Program
    {
        private static double Negyzet(int alap, int kitevo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Kérem a hatvány alapját!");
            alap = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Kérem a hatvány kitevojet!");
            kitevo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            return Math.Pow(alap, kitevo);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Kérem adja meg milyen műveletet szeretne elvégezni!\n\n+ összeadás\n- kivonás\n* szorzás\n/ osztás\n^hatványozás\n\nVálasztott művelet:");
            string muvelet = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (muvelet)
            {
                case (muvelet == "^"): Console.WriteLine("A hatvány értéke:     {0}", Negyzet(0, 0)); break;
                default: break;
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch).

Comment: @Symon From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#-pattern-matching-with-the-switch-statement): `If expr and constant are integral types, the C# equality operator determines whether the expression returns true (that is, whether expr == constant). Otherwise, the value of the expression is determined by a call to the static Object.Equals(expr, constant) method.`

Comment: Well, the basic difference of `if` and `switch` is that the latter might make use of a lookup table, if possible, which is much faster when many clauses are needed, while the former always evaluates the clauses consecutively.

Comment: so again, thank you guys for the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

muvelet is a string while `muvelet == "^"` is a comarision which is boolean (it is either true or false

```
switch(muvelet)  
{
     case "^":
         // code for when it is equal to "^"
          break;
    //other cases
    default:
         //it is unknown character
}
```

note that the type in your switch (that is a string in this case) should match the type of cases

Answer (score 3):

You're using the `case` clause in a wrong way. It expects integer or `String` values - but you supply a `Boolean` value. It's easy to fix that, however. Just write the `case` clause like that:

```
case "^":
```

Then it should compile and work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Until C# 6, the switch instruction was reserved for primitive types. You can now switch to patterns.

[Pattern Matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching)

**And so you can do that kind of thing :**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Print("+", 2, 2);
        Print("-", 2, 2);
        Print("/", 2, 2);
        Print("*", 2, 2);
        Print("^", 2, 2);
        Print("%", 2, 2);
        Print(" ", 2, 2);
        Print("", 2, 2);
        Console.Read();
    }
    static void Print(string op, int nmb1, int nmb2)
    {
        var res = Compute(op, nmb1, nmb2);
        Console.WriteLine(res != null ?
            $"{nmb1} {op} {nmb2} = {res}" :
            $"invalid {op?.Trim()} operator description");
    }

    static int? Compute(string op,int nmb1,int nmb2)
    {
        switch (op)
        {
            case "+":
                return nmb1 + nmb2;
            case "-":
                return nmb1 - nmb2;
            case "*":
                return nmb1 * nmb2;
            case "/":
                return nmb1 / nmb2;
            case "%":
                return nmb1 % nmb2;
            case "^":
                return nmb1 ^ nmb2;
            case var o when (o?.Trim().Length ?? 0) == 0:
                // white space
                return null;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**console output :**

```
2 + 2 = 4
2 - 2 = 0
2 / 2 = 1
2 * 2 = 4
2 ^ 2 = 0
2 % 2 = 0
invalid operator 
invalid operator
```